# PyCharm: ModuleNotFoundError although module (scipy) is installed

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm, interpreter, site-packages

I am working with PyCharm and encountered a ModuleNotFoundError when I try running a script that was working about half a year ago. It says:

```
File "lalala/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import scipy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

I am using PyCharm 2023.3.3 (Community Edition), python 3.10 and scipy 1.12. No virtual environment, all is installed globally.

When I check my system, scipy is properly installed in `~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/` . Also the PyCharms Package Manager can find scipy and the site-packages path is known by PyCharm. I checked the interpreter settings.

Other site packages like numpy are installed in the same location and are found properly. I can not understand where the scipy problem comes from.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages` doesn't look global. Is the setup of your project's Python SDK in PyCharm including that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, weird. Did you installed with pip or with OS package manager. Anyways, try  the another with you not installed with.

With pip is

```
pip install scipy
```

with your OS package manager, normally, the package is named `python-scipy`

Comment: Yes, pip install scipy is what i did. I did a new installation with apt. Nothing changes. And i should add that running my script from command line doesnt give me the error. So i suspect pycharm is the problem. But I don't know where else to search for the problem.